# Not able to hide ActionBar (Android)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i am trying to hide ActionBar in SplashScreenActivity but i am not able to hide. it always showing.

i tried this: but not worked

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

or

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

or

**this unfortunately stop app**

```
    <application
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.app.AppController"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FreeWallTheme">
            <activity
                android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

In you application's manifest file , set the following property in `<application>` TAG.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

Comment: but it will change Theme for all Activity

Comment: try

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);`

on the create activity and before setting our layout

Comment: Setting the android:theme property at the activity level in the manifest file changes it for that activity only (works in API Level 21)

Answer (score 0):

Set the following line in your theme:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a new theme tag inside activity like below:

```
 <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

You have to call it in the onCreate method